# Вопрос про cmake, add_test() и передачу аргументов в тест при генерации решения для Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gtest

Скажите, пожалуйста, поддерживает ли команда `add_test()` из `cmake` добавление переданных для теста аргументов в проект в `Visual Studio`?

Я делаю так:

```
add_test(${PROJECT_NAME} "123")
```

Где `${PROJECT_NAME}` - это цель, которая собирает исполняемый файл.

Проблема в том, что если генерируется решение для `Visual Studio`, то в проекте сборки исполняемого файла нет никаких параметров, которые передаются собираемому приложению.

Более того, даже если запускать обозначенный тест через `GTest adapter`, то тест все равно не получает никаких аргументов, кроме адреса, откуда этот тест запустили.

Скажите, можно ли решить эту проблему?

Comment: Собираемому приложению при сборке не передается никаких аргументов. В `add_test` указываются параметры, которые будет передавать запускаемому исполняемому файлу утилита `ctest`. Вам наверное надo делать .runsettings

Comment: @user7860670, я уже начал что-то такое подозревать... Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим [официальную документацию](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/add_test.html?highlight=add_test). Как видим `add_test` поддерживает ключевые `NAME` и `COMMAND` и если указывать без них, то вызов выглядит как:

```
add_test(<name> <command> <args>)
```

Чтобы у вас не возникало путаницы, указывайте ключевые слова явно

```
add_test(NAME my_test COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME} "123")
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал указывать ключевые слова явно, но разницы в поведении не заметил. Сейчас попробую ваш вариант, спасибо.

Comment: Предложенный вариант не работает. Переданные аргументы не попадают ни в проект в генерируемом решении `VS`, ни в список аргументов теста, при запуске теста через `VS`.

Comment: @MGNeo а теперь объясните что за список аргументов теста и что делает VS при "запуске тэста"

Comment: Я имею в виду то, что попадает в `argv`.

Comment: @MGNeo это понятно, данный способ, как раз-таки и добавляет аргументы для тестовой проги. А вот что делает VS при якобы "запуске тэста"? Для начала запустите `cmake --build <path to build directory> --target test`. Если все отработало как нужно, то проблема в VS (ну или вы просто не то пытаетесь запустить)

Comment: Я проверил тот файл, который генерируется из `cmake`, в котором находится список всех добавленных к выполнению тестов со всеми параметрами для них. Там все нормально. А вот в студию переданные через `add_test()` параметры не попадают.

Comment: @MGNeo по-моему (я не знаком со студией и впринципе избегаю IDE), но вы путаете запуск теста, с запуском программы. Для тэста и программы cmake генерит разные цели и вы, я полагаю, пытаетесь запустить цель программы, а не теста. Если же я не прав - то проблема в IDE и тут я вам не помогу